# How to ensure all items in a collection match a filter in Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have Azure Cognitive Search running, and my index is working as expected.
We are trying to add a security filter into the search, based on the current users permissions.
The users permissions are coming to me in as IEnumerable, but I am currently selecting just a string[] and passing that into my filter, then do a string.join, which looks like this.

```
permission1, permission2, permission3, permission4
```

In our SQL database, we have a view that is where the index is getting it's data from. There is a column on the view called RequiredPermissions, it is a Collection(Edm.string) in the index, and the data looks like this.

```
[ 'permission1', 'permission2', 'permission3' ]
```

The requirement is that for a record to return in the results, a user's permissions must contain all of the RequiredPermissions for that record.

So if we have a user with the following permissions

```
permission1, permission3, permission5
```

And we have the following records

```
Id, SearchText, Type,     Permissions
1,  abc,        User,     [ 'permission1', 'permission2' ]
2,  abc.pdf,    Document, [ 'permission1' ]
3,  abc,        Thing,    [ 'permission1', 'permission3' ]
4,  abc,        Stuff,    [ 'permission3', 'permission4' ]
```

If the user searched for 'abc' and these four results would come back, I need to $filter results that do not have the proper permissions. So I would expect the following results

```
Id, Returned, Reason
1,  no,       the user does not have permission2
2,  yes,      the user has permission1 and nothing else is needed
3,  yes,      the user has both permission1 and permission3
4,  no,       the user does not have permission4
```

If I run the following filter, then I get back anything that has permission1 or permission3, which is not acceptable, since the user should not see items Id 1 or 4

```
RequiredPermissions/any(role: search.in(role, 'permission1, permission3', ','))
```

If I run this filter, then I get nothing back, everything is rejected, because no records have permission5, and the user has it

```
RequiredPermissions/all(role: not search.in(role, 'permission1, permission3', ','))
```

If I try to run the search using 'all' and without the 'not' I get the following error

```
RequiredPermissions/all(role: search.in(role, 'permission1, permission3', ','))

Invalid expression: Invalid lambda expression. Found a test for equality or inequality where the opposite was expected in a lambda expression that iterates over a field of type Collection(Edm.String). For 'any', please use expressions of the form 'x eq y' or 'search.in(...)'. For 'all', please use expressions of the form 'x ne y', 'not (x eq y)', or 'not search.in(...)'.\r\nParameter name: $filter
```

So it seems that I cannot use the 'not' with 'any', and I must use the 'not' with 'all'

What I wish for is a way to say that a user has all the permissions in their list that is in the RequiredPermissions column.

I am currently just working in Postman using the RestApi to solve this, but I will eventually move this into .Net.

Answer (score 4):

Your scenario can't be implemented with `Collection(Edm.String)` due to the limitations on how `all` and `any` work on such collections (documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-query-understand-collection-filters)).

Fortunately, there is an alternative. You can model permissions as a collection of complex types, which allows you to use `all` the way that you need to implement your permissions model. Here is a JSON example of how the field would be defined:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "fields": [ 
        { "name": "Id", "type": "Edm.String", "key": true }, 
        { "name": "RequiredPermissions", "type": "Collection(Edm.ComplexType)", "fields": [{ "name": "Name", "type": "Edm.String" }] }
    ]
}
```

Here is a JSON example of what a document would look like with its permissions defined:

```
{ "@search.action": "upload", "Id": "1", "RequiredPermissions": [{"Name": "permission1"}, {"Name": "permission2"}] }
```

Here is how you could construct a filter that has the desired effect:

```
RequiredPermissions/all(perm: search.in(perm/Name, 'permission1,permission3,permission5'))
```

While this works, you are strongly advised to test the performance of this solution with a realistic set of data. Under the hood, `all` is executed as a negated `any`, and negated queries can sometimes perform poorly with the type of inverted indexes used by a search engine.

Also, please be aware that there is currently [a limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity#index-limits) on the number of elements in all complex collections across a document. This limit is currently 3000. So if `RequiredPermissions` were the only complex collection in your index, this means you could have at most 3000 permissions defined per document.

Comment: that sounds awesome, and I will try it when I am allowed to get back to this. for now we implemented it by filtering the results in code. This is less than ideal, but it works for now. I douibt we will ever have thousands of permissions, so I think we are ok there, right now there are about 20, we got some room.